# Is there some sort of "no newline at eof" rules for bash scripts?

Tags: shell-script, terminal

I have two files, an env file and a run file. When I deploy them to my Ubuntu Server box I get the error:

> ./start-admin: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file

If I deploy and then add a newline to the end of the file, it will show the error. If I then remove it the error goes away. If I deploy again and don't add the newline, it still shows the error, but if I then add a newline the error goes away. What could possibly cause that?

Below are my scripts:

env:

```
if [ "x${WD}" == "x" ];  then echo "missing required conf \"\${WD}\"" >&2; exit -1; fi

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
export JAR_FILE="$WD/mfa-admin.jar"
export MYSQL_URL=url1
export MYSQL_USER=root
export MYSQL_PASSWORD=pwd
export DB_URL=url2
export DB_USER=user
export DB_PASSWORD=pwd2

export EMAIL_HOST=mail-inbox
export EMAIL_PORT=25
export EMAIL_PERMISSION=false
export FAKE_EMAIL=email
export ACTIVATION_URL=url

export BIND_HOST=0.0.0.0
export BIND_PORT=8282
```

start:

```
WD=`dirname $0`;

JAVA_OPTS=""

if [ -r "$WD/admin.env.conf" ]; then
  . $WD/admin.env.conf
fi

# required stuff
if [ "x${JAVA_HOME}" == "x" ];                              then echo "missing required conf \"\${JAVA_HOME}\""                                                  >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${JAR_FILE}" == "x" ];                               then echo "missing required conf \"\${JAR_FILE}\""                                                   >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${MYSQL_URL}" == "x" ];                   then echo "missing required conf \"\${MYSQL_URL}\""        >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${MYSQL_USER}" == "x" ];                  then echo "missing required conf \"\${MYSQL_USER}\""       >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${MYSQL_PASSWORD}" == "x" ];              then echo "missing required conf \"\${MYSQL_PASSWORD}\""   >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${DB_URL}" == "x" ];                      then echo "missing required conf \"\${DB_URL}\""                            >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${DB_USER}" == "x" ];                     then echo "missing required conf \"\${DB_USER}\""                           >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${DB_PASSWORD}" == "x" ];                 then echo "missing required conf \"\${DB_PASSWORD}\""                       >&2; exit -1; fi

if [ "x${EMAIL_HOST}" == "x" ];                  then echo "missing required conf \"\${EMAIL_HOST}\""                       >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${EMAIL_PORT}" == "x" ];                  then echo "missing required conf \"\${EMAIL_PORT}\""                       >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${EMAIL_PERMISSION}" == "x" ];            then echo "missing required conf \"\${EMAIL_PERMISSION}\""                 >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${FAKE_EMAIL}" == "x" ];                  then echo "missing required conf \"\${FAKE_EMAIL}\""                       >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${ACTIVATION_URL}" == "x" ];              then echo "missing required conf \"\${ACTIVATION_URL}\""                   >&2; exit -1; fi

if [ "x${BIND_HOST}" == "x" ];                    then echo "missing required conf \"\${BIND_HOST}\""                         >&2; exit -1; fi
if [ "x${BIND_PORT}" == "x" ];                    then echo "missing required conf \"\${BIND_PORT}\""                         >&2; exit -1; fi

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmysql.URL=\"${MYSQL_URL}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmysql.USER=\"${MYSQL_USER}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dmysql.PASSWORD=\"${MYSQL_PASSWORD}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Ddb.URL=\"${DB_URL}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Ddb.USER=\"${DB_USER}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Ddb.PASSWORD=\"${DB_PASSWORD}\" "

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DEMAIL_HOST=\"${EMAIL_HOST}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DEMAIL_PORT=\"${EMAIL_PORT}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DEMAIL_PERMISSION=\"${EMAIL_PERMISSION}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DFAKE_EMAIL=\"${FAKE_EMAIL}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DACTIVATION_URL=\"${ACTIVATION_URL}\" "

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DBIND_HOST=\"${BIND_HOST}\" "
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -DBIND_PORT=\"${BIND_PORT}\" "

JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

eval \"$JAVA\" $JAVA_OPTS -cp "${WD}:${JAR_FILE}" VertxNode
```

Comment: Does your script has DOS line endings?

Comment: hi, i just started using a mac. what do you mean by DOS line ending?

Comment: @jordanm i dont know if it makes a difference, but i started working on the script on a windows machine, then later transfer to a mac.

Comment: try to convert it to unix-style line endings with `dos2unix`

Comment: @yaojiang yes, that does make a difference. See Serge's comment.

Comment: i see, i will try and rewrite the whole thing on the mac. thanks!

Comment: You don't have to rewrite, just use dos2unix as suggested. Windows, Mac and Linux use different characters for line endings, that's all.

Comment: There's an error in the `start-admin` script, but you didn't post a script with that name. Either you didn't post the relevant script or you didn't report the name of the script correctly. (Copy-paste!) We can't help you if you don't give us precise data.

Comment: Note that you must begin your scripts with `#!/bin/bash`. Otherwise they will be executed with `/bin/sh` and not bash. You could make your scripts compatible with `/bin/sh` by using `[ "x${foo}" = x ]` instead of `==`, that's the only bash extension that you use. You would still need to start the script with [`#!/bin/sh`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Comment: Run your script as `bash -x start-admin` then post debug output.

Comment: instead of single `[` use `[[` , see why[link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices)

Comment: well amazingly, i rewrote the whole thing on the mac(error), add "#!/bin/bash"(error), double-triple checked my "" [] if/then/fi(error), use my coworkers script(which is basically the same format, just diff variables) it still gives me error. insane.

Comment: I think mdpc might be is on the right track in his answer. If one of your variables contains odd number of quotes, for example the last eval might fail because of that. Run it with `bash -x` to see what's happening. Maybe you have some stray quotes in the sourced configuration file - that would cause the error on line 10 (right after sourcing the file).

Comment: @peterph probable. cant believe a bash script is kicking my ass.. a script that i copy/paste/change vars..

Answer (score 2):

When I have obtained this message, it is the result of mismatched `` ` ``, `'`, or `"` strings within the script.  Sometimes this also happens with mismatched if/then/fi, do/while, or case/esac statements.  I'd strongly check out your scripting closely.